# need help with acts_as_ferret and will_paginate to play nice together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ferret, acts-as-ferret

I have installed will_paginate and acts_as_ferret on my system for ruby rails.
My paginate seems to work fine before installing acts_as_ferret.  When I put in the code to do searching I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Community#search  

Showing app/views/community/_result_summary.rhtml where line #3 raised:  

undefined method `total_entries' for []:Array  

Extracted source (around line #3):  

1: <% if @users %>  
2: <p>  
3: Found <%= pluralize(@users.total_entries, "match") %>.  
4: </p>  
5: <% end %>
```

If I take out the search function, paginate works but it's pointless because I can't do searches.  Can any one help me out on this one??

Thanks!!

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

undefined method `total_entries' for []:Array

eror itself shows that you are calling total_entries method which is not array method.
you get more than one user in your @users.
try

```
1: <% unless @users.blank? %>  
2: <p>  
3: Found <%= pluralize(@users[0].total_entries, "match") %>.  
4: </p>  
5: <% end %>
```

EDITED
TRY

```
1: <% unless @users.blank? %>  
2: <p>  
3: Found <%= pluralize(@users.length, "match") %>.  
4: </p>  
5: <% end %>
```

Comment: still getting the same error this time on line 3.  Ruby is telling me that undefined method 'total_entries'

Comment: by the way -- with this code -- the search is blank but the paginate returns an error.

Comment: As far as I know, `total_entries` is an array method. It's from `will_paginate`.

Comment: Salil:  This was close!!  The paginate works -- but the advanced search using ferret now returns blank (nothing).  What information can I give you to help me debug this??  I am a total newbie when it comes to RoR!!

Thanks for this!!!

Stephen